# Display notification when user comes online

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, notifications

I know I am probably doing this the worst way possible and to top it off it isn't even working right now.

So what I am looking to do is display a notification when each user comes online. I have some ajax:

```
<!-- display online status notification Script -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'check-online-status.php',
            cache: false,
            error: function(e){
                alert(e);
            },
            success: function(response){
                // Reload the page to refresh data from database
               window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 10000);
            }
        });   
    });
</script>
```

that will check to see which users are online in the check-online-status.php file:

```
<?php
//// require the db config file ////
require("../config.php");
//// Get users ////
$query5 = "SELECT online_status, last_activity FROM users ";
$stmt5 = $db->prepare($query5);
$stmt5->execute();
$recent_user = $stmt5->fetchAll();
?>

<?php foreach($recent_user as $row) { ?>
<?php
    // Check online status
    if($row['online_status'] == 'Online'){
        $online_status = 'online';
    } 

    // Get last activity date/time and compare to todays date/time
    if(!is_null($row['last_activity'])){
        $start_date = new DateTime($row['last_activity']);
        $end_date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"));
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
        $last_activity = "Last Active: " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months,  ".$interval->d." days, ".$interval->h." hours, ".$interval->i." minutes "."and ".$interval->s." seconds "."ago";

        if($interval->s == 0){
            $last_activity = "Last Active: Now";
        }
    }
    else {
        $last_activity = 'None';
    }

?>  
<?php if($online_status == 'online' && $last_activity == 'Last Active: Now' ){ ?>
    <!-- Launch a SmallBox on form load -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var username = <?php echo ''.$row['username'].''.'is online'; ?>;
            $.bigBox({
                title: "Online",
                content: username,
                width: 250,
                color: "#2ECC71",
                timeout: 5000,
                delay: 0.5,
            });


        }); 
    </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

I am using a script called [Metro Notification](http://codecanyon.net/item/metro-notifications/3903495) to display the notification box.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. When I inspect with firebug I can see the info looks correct with the notification JS (located in the check-online-status.php file):

```
<!-- Launch a SmallBox on form load -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var username = user1 is online;
            $.bigBox({
                title: "Online",
                content: username,
                width: 250,
                color: "#2ECC71",
                timeout: 5000,
                delay: 0.5,
            });


        }); 
    </script>


        <!-- Launch a SmallBox on form load -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var username = user2 is online;
            $.bigBox({
                title: "Online",
                content: username,
                width: 250,
                color: "#2ECC71",
                timeout: 5000,
                delay: 0.5,
            });


        }); 
    </script>
```

if 2 users are online this is the code I get above.

Comment: Just curious but why would you reload the page making an ajax request and not just initiate another ajax request? Also, if you want to reload the page, why not just check in php on reload instead of loading the php page an initiating an ajax request to load another php page?

Comment: This is a poor implementation of mixing Javascript with PHP, which could be heavily improved via fixing `check-online-status.php` to respond like an API and using the data returned from said script in javascript instead of refreshing a php page which then autoloads a javascript method o.o

Comment: To add to the above comments, why are you limiting your sql results to 5 users? If you want to get a list of the online users, check the `online_status` value in sql.

Comment: That was a mistake in my query because I copied and pasted from another query and forgot to change it. I know this is poor implementation that's why I'm posting here in hopes to get some examples of what I should do. I'm an not great with Ajax, jquery, etc. so any examples would be greatly appreciated